# Vue: watching a v-model's 'value' in a component

Tags: vue.js

I have this component which has a v-model directive:
`<my-component v-model="someData.someProp"></my-component>`

Now, I'd like to be able to watch this piece of data inside the component and make changes based on this model changing via outside influences. So here's what I tried and it's not working:

```
    watch : {
        value (newVal, oldVal) {
           // ...
        }
    }
```

It seems like it should work, or something comparable should be out there, but I just can't find it right now.

EDIT:
The most common answers I found and provided center on using the watcher to watch the data as if it's inside the parent component - but I'd like to watch it inside the child component without concern of what's going on in the parent.
I'm able to work around this by not using v-model and using simple named properties such as `:my-data="someData.someProp"` at which point I can successfully watch a `myData` variable inside the child component. I can also use `@input` to set the data back in the parent component if it's changed from within. But `v-model` is shorter and if there's a way to use that instead of a workaround that would be preferable.

Comment: If i correctly understand what you want, you dont need to watch the value, as it is reactive you can just use it in computed or in your template directly with v-if or other triggers

Comment: I was trying to use the `value` in a computed block inside the component so that the computed data could get updated based on the v-model but it just got "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to pass a prop to your child component from your parent one and watch it in your child.

Assuming you have something like this in your parent:

```
<div>
   <my-component v-model="someData.someProp"></my-component>
</div>
```

I understand you are getting undefined for that prop when you watch it, which is normal because you should pass it like this:

```
<my-component :myValue="someData.someProp"></my-component>
```

Then you should have access to the prop trought `this.myValue`.
If `someData.someProp` changes on the parent component it will automatically reflect on the child one.

Again this is what I could understand from your explanation and the amount of code you provided.

Comment: So using both v-model and :myProp at least cuts down on writing a separate @input event handler. But I am having to pass the same thing in twice in two different attributes. I will accept this if nothing else comes in way of some more elaborate explanation of why this works this way in the next few days.